# Adding characters to $config[permitted_uri_chars]

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I think I need to add several characters to the $config[permitted_uri_chars] but I don't know which one is causing the issue and how to place the character. This is what I get when I access the page:

```
An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

This is the address:

```
http://localhost/ci_bootstrap/index.php/home/edit_user/1'%7D
```

And this is my $config:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Can you help a noob? Thank you.

Comment: I've got to ask the reason behind the last bit of the url being 1'%7D.  Is there a good reason for it?

Comment: It;s been generated that way. Don't know why..

Comment: This is all very straightforward and would have taken 30 seconds for you to try it yourself.   The `'` character appears in your URI but it's not listed within the `permitted_uri_chars` option.  Simply add it.

Comment: *"It;s been generated that way. Don't know why."* ~ Well, we don't know either.   We cannot see your code that would have generated that URI or how it came into your OP.  Seems like that's the *real* problem you need to solve.

Comment: 'a-z 0-9~%.:_,\-'; OR 'a-z 0-9~%\.\:_\' both are check

Comment: 1'%7D turns out to be 1'}. So your intended id is indeed a huge BUG in your code. Fix your code instead of trying to make changes to accept something that is obviously very very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You did not allow `'` in `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';`
So you have to include it:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = "a-z 0-9~%.:_'\-";
```

Comment: It's a good idea to put `-` after backslash as `-` is a regex metacharacter